# Changing GridLayout row/column count at runtime in android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-gridlayout

I am new in android development. I am trying to use a GridLayout to fulfill my UI design.

This is the scenario:

I defined a GridLayout in xml file as following

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/linearLayoutBottomLeft"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/linearLayoutTopLeft"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView" >
</GridLayout>
```

Then, I set it in my activity's onCreate() method like following:

```
GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
gridLayout.invalidate();
int rowNumber = 4;
int colNumber = 4;
gridLayout.setRowCount(rowNumber);
gridLayout.setColumnCount(colNumber);
```

so far so good, everything is working well.
However, I also have some buttons there. In button's click event, I changed the rowNumber and colNumber, set them at runtime. It cause some error I think...

So my question is whether the row number and column number can be set at runtime for gridLayout.

If this is not allowed in android, what is a good practice to realize a GUI like what I described above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do a gridLayout.removeAllChildren().

Invalidate is a way of letting the View system know that the content of the View has changed and that it needs to be redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I figured out some way to solve this problem.

In the xml file, I replaced the GridLayout with a LinearLayout, and made the girdlayout dynamically added as the child of linearlayout. Now the row/column count can be changed in button click event handler.

I am not sure if this is a good way to do it and any performance hit will arise.